# How to solve "Component auth has not been registered yet" error in Firebase 9 + Nuxt 3

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm working on an online store and trying to implement Google OAuth via Firebase. I've already successfully integrated Firebase services like storage and Firestore, but I'm encountering an error when I try to add Firebase Auth to my Nuxt 3 app. Specifically, I'm getting a "Component auth has not been registered yet" error

```
[nitro] [dev] [unhandledRejection] Error: Component auth has not been registered yet                     06:35:21
    at Provider.initialize (/Users/swanandkadam/Desktop/Work/underground/@firebase/component:233:19)
    at initializeAuth (file:///Users/swanandkadam/Desktop/Work/underground/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/totp-abcc15a3.js:2947:27)
    at Module.getAuth (file:///Users/swanandkadam/Desktop/Work/underground/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/totp-abcc15a3.js:6575:18)
    at setup (/Users/swanandkadam/Desktop/Work/underground/pages/Login.vue:25:33)
    at _sfc_main.setup (/Users/swanandkadam/Desktop/Work/underground/pages/Login.vue:52:23)
    at callWithErrorHandling (/Users/swanandkadam/Desktop/Work/underground/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:171:22)
    at setupStatefulComponent (/Users/swanandkadam/Desktop/Work/underground/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:7194:29)
    at setupComponent (/Users/swanandkadam/Desktop/Work/underground/node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:7149:11)
    at renderComponentVNode (/Users/swanandkadam/Desktop/Work/underground/node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:628:17)
    at renderVNode (/Users/swanandkadam/Desktop/Work/underground/node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:755:22)
```

I've tried deleting the node_modules folder, package-lock.json, and reinstalling with npm install, as I saw on Github that this can fix the issue. However, this didn't work for me.

To investigate further, I created a new Nuxt 3 app solely for testing Firebase Auth. However, I'm still encountering the same error, even though I haven't written any other code or installed any other packages besides Firebase.

**MY STACK:**

Nuxt 3
Firebase 9

**Package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18",
    "nuxt": "^3.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.12.0"
  }
}
```

**firebase.js file**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
// See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#config-object
const firebaseConfig = {
  //... ( hidden for security purposes )

};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// Initialize Firebase Authentication and get a reference to the service
const auth = getAuth(app);
export default auth;
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Expected outcome: Successful implementation of Firebase Auth for Google OAuth in my online store.

Actual outcome: Encountering a "Component auth has not been registered yet" error when trying to add Firebase Auth to my Nuxt 3 app, both in my main project and in a new project created solely for testing Firebase Auth.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error today and found a solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nuxt/comments/y5e42k/component_auth_has_not_been_registered_yet_error/)
Basically you just have to rename your "firebase.js" to "firebase.client.js". This did the trick for me. I hope this helps you too!

Cheers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).